# Smooth Riemann Mapping theorem not clear

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't fully understand the "Smooth Riemann mapping theorem" (it's called like that in Wikipedia). It goes as follows:

Let $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a simply connected set with a smooth boundary and $\mathbb{D}$ the open unit disk. According to the Riemann mapping theorem, there exists a conformal(biholomorphic) map $f\colon G\to \mathbb{D}$. If like here the boundary is smooth, then there is a continuation on $\bar{G}$, $\hat{f}\colon \bar{G}\to \mathbb{D}$ which is continous.

Until here I understand everything but here is the, for me, complicated part.

$\hat{f}$ is bijective as a function from $\bar{G}$ to $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ if every boundary point $z_0\in \partial G$ has as many image points on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ as $z_0$ has been passed by the boundary curve $\partial G$.

Look for example on the Joukowski-Transform $j\colon\mathbb{D}\to \hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus[-2,2]$, $j(z) = z + \frac{1}{z}$ ($\hat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$). This function is conformal and so there is an conformal inverse $k\colon G=\hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus[-2,2]\to \mathbb{D}$

Now according to my lecture notes $\partial G = [2,-2) + [-2,2)$ so every point on the boundary of  $G$ is passed two times by the boundary curve and for $z\in \partial G$ it is $|j^{-1}(z)\in \partial\mathbb{D}| = 2$.

Now I am asking myself how there can be a "function" $\hat{k}\colon \bar{G} \to \bar{\mathbb{D}}$?
What is $\hat{k}(z)$ for $z\in [-2,2]$?

What to they mean by "every boundary point $z_0\in \partial G$ has as many image points...", since every point only has only one image point, otherwise it wouldn't be a function?

Comment: $G$ doesn't have a smooth boundary in the sense the term is usually used (which implies for instance that $G$ would lie on one side of $\partial G$, and the complement to the other).